# How to profile a non-web application within Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, profiling

I have a class with a main(String[] args) method.  It is the entry point into a Swing application, which runs fine for the most part.  Some operations within the application are slow, so I thought I'd try the profiler in Eclipse Juno.

When I right-click on the .java file in the Eclipse's Project Explorer, go to "Run As->" my options are "Run on Server", "Java Application", and "Run Configurations ...".  Similar for "Debug As->", except there is "Debug Configurations ...".

However, if I right-click and go down to "Profile As->", the only options are "Profile on Server" and "Profile Configurations ...".

I see no "Profiling" perspective available.  I can't figure out whether the feature has been removed or [perhaps discontinued altogether](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/project_info/devplans/EclipseTPTPProjectPlan2010.htm) (without a replacement, yet it seems SOMETHING is there), if I need to install an additional component or module, if I've installed something that conflicts with that feature, if there is a configuration setting that needs to be changed, or if it doesn't apply for some reason.  Google gives lots of unrelated results for every search query I've come up with so far.

So my question is: What needs to be done to run the profiler on a desktop app, preferably within Eclipse (Juno)?

Comment: Is this something that would have been better asked on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question appears to have been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713940/eclipse-java-profiler

While the question dates from before TPTP was discontinued, the answers that suggest alternatives are all still relevant.

Comment: The most prominent solution on this page points to VisualVM, which can be used separately.  Googling for VisualVM and Eclipse leads to: http://visualvm.java.net/eclipse-launcher.html ... we have a winner! Thanks a lot.